Why does RigidBody.MovePosition ignore collisions?
private void Update()
{
if (!grabTransform) return;

        Vector3 newPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, grabTransform.position, Time.deltaTime * 20f);
        rigidbody.MovePosition(newPosition);
    
        Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, grabTransform.rotation, Time.deltaTime * 20f);
        rigidbody.MoveRotation(newRotation);
        
        rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        rigidbody.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero; 
}

I'm currently developing a feature that allows picking up and carrying an object. When holding an object,  it is implemented to follow the Transform in the front direction of the camera. However, when turning my head towards a wall, the carried object sometimes gets stuck as it intersects with the wall.

I want the object to naturally collide with walls without getting stuck.
When I use Velocity or Addforce, it moves too much, like a spring.

The way to do this is to use Rigidbody.SweepTest to check if MovePosition would get stuck in a wall, and then project the movement vector onto the wall's normal and use that as the new movement vector.

@Verpous afaik MovePosition should actually respect collisions

if the colliders are triggers it wont respond to collider code and expectations
